# Grouping Data by its class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've data iris in UCI. I want to group it by its class.
I used this code:

```
def splitData(trainingSet, classedTrainingSet=[], listClass=[]):
    for x in range(len(trainingSet)):
        classData = trainingSet[x][-1] #string
        if classData not in listClass:
            listClass.append(classData)
        for y in range(len(listClass)):
            if listClass[y] == classData:
                classedTrainingSet.append((y, trainingSet[x]))
```

The error was:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How can I group the data by its class?

Comment: The code you pasted is not indented correctly, can you edit and fix it?

Comment: which line you are getting the error???

Comment: Don't use `range()` and indexed access, python `for` loops are made to iterate on a sequence, ie : `for char in ['a', 'b', 'c']: print(char)`. This is more efficient, much more readable, works with every iterable (not only sequences), and avoids quite a few IndexError (note that it will necessarily solve your problem here but anyway). Also, beware of the "mutable default argument" gotcha cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if the tuple is empty while getting the last element

```
In [1]: emptyTuple = ()    
In [2]: emptyTuple[-1]    
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

`classData = trainingSet[x][-1] #string` can replaced with

```
if len(trainingSet[x]) > 0:
    classData = trainingSet[x][-1]
```